# Skype randomly crashes on Android 2.1update1

Tags: skype

After upgrading to Skype 2.8.0.920... it randomly crashes (I mean just Skype... I just suddenly hear that Skype is logging out..randomly, AFAIK it crashes..)... BUT WHY?? I can revert to an older version of Skype... My phone is a LG GT540..

Comment: Have you tried clearing the app data? Force stopping the app? Restarting the phone?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed a Skype 2.6.0.95 apk (which is an earlier version) and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know for sure unless you view logcat. Use adb which comes with [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and execute the command logcat.

I usually do the following steps to find out what causes an application to crash:

1. Enable USB debugging (Settings -> Developer Options -> USB debugging)
2. Plug in USB cable to your phone and connect it to your machine.
3. Run [adb logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#logcat)
4. Run the application and try to make it crash while viewing the logcat.